# density function of max of joint distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

The Joint density of x and y is $\frac{2}{9}*(x^3+y^3)$

for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$,and $o$ otherwise.

Find $E[max[(x,y)]$
I'm having some trouble on how to find density function of max(x,y)

solution so far

$z=max(x,y)$ and $P(max(x,y)<z)=F_z(z)=P(X<z,Y<z)$

Comment: that's nice! Now integrate your joint density to calculate the last probability

Comment: You don't need the density function of $\max(X,Y)$ to find the expected value. I suggest calculating $E[\max(X,Y)]$ directly as an integral in two dimensions.

Comment: wait integrate it how?do I need to find the joint cdf?

Comment: Okay is integrating directly a better method that looking for density function?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum between $X$ and $Y$ is smaller than $t$ if and only if both $X$ and $Y$ are smaller than $t$. So the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the maximum is
$$
Prob[\max(X,Y)<t]=\int_0^t dx\int_0^t dy\ f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ ,
$$
from which you can deduce the corresponding pdf $p_\max (t)$ by differentiating with respect to $t$. Therefore
$$
p_{max}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}Prob[\max(X,Y)<t]=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t dx\int_0^t dy\ f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ ,
$$
where the support is $t\in [0,2]$, as the maximum between $X$ and $Y$ cannot exceeed $2$.

Computing now
$$
I(t)=\int_0^t dx\int_0^t dy\ f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_0^t dx\int_0^t dy\ \frac{2}{9}(x^3+y^3)\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1}\mathbf{1}_{0<y<2}
$$
requires splitting the cases $0<t<1$ or $1\leq t\leq 2$.

If $0<t<1$, then
$$
I(t)=\int_0^t dx\int_0^t dy\ \frac{2}{9}(x^3+y^3)=\frac{t^5}{9}\ .
$$

If $1\leq t\leq 2$, then
$$
I(t)=\int_0^1 dx\int_0^t dy\ \frac{2}{9}(x^3+y^3)=\frac{1}{18}(t+t^4)\ .
$$
One can then check that
$$
p_{max}(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{5t^4}{9} &\mbox{ for }0\leq t\leq 1\\
\frac{1}{18}(1+4t^3)&\mbox{ for }1\leq t\leq 2\ ,
\end{cases}
$$
is correctly normalized,
$$
\int_0^2 dt\ p_{max}(t)=1.
$$
The expectation value is now easy to compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X,Y)]=\int_0^2 dt\ t\ p_{max}(t)=\frac{839}{540}\ .
$$

Answer (score 0):

$E[\max(X,Y)]$ is the integral of the joint density $f(x,y)$ times the function 
that is $x$ on the green triangle, but $y$ on the yellow region. You have to compute two double integrals and add them, but you don't need the density function of $\max(X,Y)$ at all.

[image]